How to Add Headers or Categories When Selecting Specific Ranges in Results
how can I add headers to display categories like DATE, TOTAL, NAME, etc.? Right now, I can only see the results.
function showInputBox(){

 var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
 var input = ui.prompt("Please enter your rep name.",ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

if(input.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Monitoring (Database)");
  var data = ws.getRange("A2:X" + ws.getLastRow()).getValues();
  var userSelectedRep = input.getResponseText().toLowerCase();
  var newData = data.filter(function(r){ return r[23] .toLowerCase() == userSelectedRep});
  var selectedColumns = newData.map(function (r) {
    return [r[10], r[9], r[1], r[17], r[18], r[19], r[20], r[21], r[22]];
  });

  if (newData.length > 0){
  var newWs = ss.insertSheet(userSelectedRep);
  newWs.getRange(3, 3, selectedColumns.length, selectedColumns[0].length).setValues(selectedColumns);
  } else {
    ui.alert ("No Matching data found for the entered name.");
  } 
  
  } else {
    ui.alert("Operation Canceled.");
  }
}

I tried to change the getrange to A1:X but the result is the same. please see below the screenshot.
This is the result and i want to display also the header

Please provide minimal reproducible example so that the community can effectively debug your code

Can you try this approach?
// Define headers
var headers = ["Header1", "Header2", "Header3", "Header4", "Header5", "Header6", "Header7", "Header8", "Header9"]; //change according to your specific needs
  // Set headers in the first row
  newWs.getRange(3, 3, 1, headers.length).setValues([headers]);
  
  // Set the filtered data starting from row 4
  newWs.getRange(4, 3, selectedColumns.length, selectedColumns[0].length).setValues(selectedColumns);


It's working thank you so much

Add headers to display categories
You can try this, this is a modified version of your code. What I did was add a hard coded header values then set it as values of a predefined range according to your needs I changed the row number of where the data and headers are being posted according to what it is on your screenshot. I am referring to these lines:
newWs.getRange(2, 3, 1, headers.length).setValues([headers]);
          
          newWs.getRange(3, 3, selectedColumns.length, selectedColumns[0].length).setValues(selectedColumns);

Sample Code
function showInputBox() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var input = ui.prompt("Please enter your rep name.", ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

  if (input.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Monitoring (Database)");
    var data = ws.getRange("A2:X" + ws.getLastRow()).getValues();
    var userSelectedRep = input.getResponseText().toLowerCase();
    var newData = data.filter(function (r) { return r[23].toLowerCase() == userSelectedRep });
    
    var selectedColumns = newData.map(function (r) {
      return [r[10], r[9], r[1], r[17], r[18], r[19], r[20], r[21], r[22]];
    });

    if (newData.length > 0) {
      var newWs = ss.insertSheet(userSelectedRep);
      
      // Define headers
      var headers = ["Header1", "Header2", "Header3", "Header4", "Header5", "Header6", "Header7", "Header8", "Header9"]; //change according to your specific needs
      
      newWs.getRange(2, 3, 1, headers.length).setValues([headers]);
      
      newWs.getRange(3, 3, selectedColumns.length, selectedColumns[0].length).setValues(selectedColumns);
    } else {
      ui.alert("No Matching data found for the entered name.");
    }
  } else {
    ui.alert("Operation Canceled.");
  }
}

Sample source sheets

Sample output

References: addValues()

Consider avoiding the disclaimer section. Every answer is written and made as how  the answerer understands the query and everyone is free to comment. This is considered unnecessary fluff and should be removed from the answer.
